# How do I convert a string to uppercase using the standard library?

Tags: c

I am trying to use a `for` loop with ASCII table to make every character in the string uppercase one by one by subtracting the letter number with 32. but I cant use the int `i` in the char `str` and `str2`. how can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLEN 200

void string_lower() {

}

void string_upper(char str) {
    char str2;
    
    int length = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str2[i] = str[i - 32];
    }
}

int main() {
    char word[STRLEN] = { 0 };
    char word1 = 97;

    printf("Write a word");
    fgets(word, STRLEN, stdin);

    string_upper(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `toupper()` would do.

Comment: Can you explain the sentence "but i cant use the int i in the char str and str2."? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `str2[i] = str[i-32];` do not do that blindly, check if the value is in the expected range (for conversion) first.

Comment: `void string_upper(char str){` The parameter should be a `char *`.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but your code has some basic problems, maybe what you need can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/6865932)

Comment: I don't think you want `str[i - 32]`.  Have you considered `str[i] - 32`?  Big difference. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `toupper()` to uppercase one character at a time. This will work for single byte character sets such as ASCII, but not for the UTF-8 encoding in general use today for non English scripts.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRLEN 200

char *string_upper(char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char word[STRLEN];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    if (fgets(word, STRLEN, stdin)) {
        printf("%s", string_upper(word);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The argument must be cast as `(unsigned char)str[i]` because `str[i]` has type `char` and `tolower()` like all functions and macros from `<ctype.h>` is only defined for values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. As `char` may be signed on some platforms, passing it directly to `tolower()` would have undefined behavior for negative values such as `'é'` and `'ÿ'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a function to convert your `String` to `upper`, maybe you can refer to the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define STRLEN 200

void string2upper(char *str){
    int cursor=0;

    while(*(str+cursor)!='\0'){
        *(str+cursor) = toupper(*(str+cursor));
        cursor++;
    }
}

void main() {

    char String1[STRLEN];
    printf("Write a word:\n");
    fgets(String1, STRLEN, stdin);

    printf("Before : %s\n", String1);
    string2upper(String1);
    printf("After : %s\n", String1);

}
```

For the `toupper()` function, I think you can refer to this [Link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/).

That has a detailed explanation and simple example to understand.

I think to know the function detail is better than only using~